# What happens to a running AWS lambda during redeployment?

Tags: aws-lambda

What happens if I deploy new version of a lambda while the old one is running?

Is the old one interrupted? Or will the new one be used to handle the next event while the old one runs as if nothing happened?

I can't find docs about it

Comment: i have checked it just now, i performed an action while saving new version of Lambda function. it ran fine without any error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I posted the same question on the AWS forums and got this reply from AWS dev

> It's what you suggest: In-flight invocations complete, without code changes or interruption, using the version of the function that was in place at the time they began. You can potentially have a function change for asynchronous invocations that experience errors or throttles, because a retry will potentially allow a new version of the function to be hit on the next attempt. While we do not abort in-flight invocations, we will aggressively eliminate copies of the old code; this typically happens within a minute of a function being updated. That means that for up to about 5-6 minutes (the max duration of a function, plus a little bit) you can experience either/both versions in use; after that, you should see only the new(ly deployed) version executing.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=270926&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

The previous version keeps running until it finishes. New invocations after the deployment is completed get the new Lambda version.

Comment: Do you have a doc stating that? It was my assumption as well, but having a doc to give to my colleagues instead of proving it would be better

Comment: No, I only have my experience where I've tested it and this is what always happens.

Comment: In my experience, new invocations may still use old code, it seems like AWS Lambda might reuse an existing instance (to avoid cold start) and it'll still have the old code. I've seen cases of new invocations randomly be executed with new and old code after a deployment (as it can have multiple instances, one with new code, another with old code).

I think the only way to avoid this is to use versioning.