# What is the behaviour if I deploy a lambda while it is running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I deployed a few lambdas to AWS via `serverless deploy` which uses cloudformation underneath. If I update an existing lambda via `serverless` which it is still running, what will happen to this lambda? Will it finish execution before update or it is interrupted by deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48169167/what-happens-to-a-running-aws-lambda-during-redeployment).

And also, according to my experience, I know this works. It will finish the current execution and the new version will be used for the next execution.